# IllegalStateException when migrating databases from SonarQube 5.3 to 5.6.2 (and 5.5)

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.3, sonarqube5.6

While trying to upgrade databases from SonarQube 5.3 to SonarQube 5.6.2, I am getting a "java.lang.IllegalStateException" with the message "Fail to decompress and deserialize source data" (originally caused by com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Stream is corrupted).

I have tried this with several different databases (we have something like 40 teams using SonarQube 5.3 and wanting to upgrade) and with both 5.5 (in case a smaller step would have worked) and 5.6.2. I get the same error.

I have upgraded all of the plugins to the latest version - except the Jira plugin which had to be removed as it is no longer compatible. Note that there is still an entry in the metrics table for it, could this be problematic?

Could anyone please tell me what might be causing this error and how to get around it?

Please let me know if any further info is required.

Thanks!!!!

Robert

The following plugins are installed on 5.6.2:

```
sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.1.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.7.jar
sonar-csharp-plugin-5.0.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.4.jar
sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.4.jar
sonar-java-plugin-4.2.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.16.0.2922.jar
sonar-pitest-plugin-0.6.jar
sonar-piwik-plugin-1.0.jar
sonar-python-plugin-1.6.jar
sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.3.jar
sonar-timeline-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1.jar
```

And these were installed on 5.3:

```
sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.0.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.6.3.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.3.jar
sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.3.1.jar
sonar-java-plugin-3.14.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.13.jar
sonar-jira-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-pitest-plugin-0.6.jar
sonar-piwik-plugin-1.0.jar
sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-timeline-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1.jar
```

Here is a bit of the log showing the end of the DB migration and the exception.

```
2016.09.25 12:46:31 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  UpdateUsersExternalIdentityWhenEmpty: migrating ===========================
2016.09.25 12:46:31 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.MassUpdate] 0 users processed (0 items/sec)
2016.09.25 12:46:31 INFO  web[DbMigration] ==  UpdateUsersExternalIdentityWhenEmpty: migrated (0.0110s) ==================
2016.09.25 12:46:31 INFO  web[DbMigration] 
2016.09.25 12:46:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient] Update center: https://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no proxy)
2016.09.25 12:46:34 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService] Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
2016.09.25 12:46:34 INFO  web[o.s.d.c.MysqlCharsetHandler] Repair case-insensitive database columns
2016.09.25 12:46:34 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics] Register metrics
2016.09.25 12:46:34 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Register rules
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1318
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:CycleBetweenPackages
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findsecbugs:WEAK_MESSAGE_DIGEST
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1724
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1701
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:SC_SUSPICIOUS_COMPARATOR_RETURN_VALUES
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:UOE_USE_OBJECT_EQUALS
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:JAO_JUNIT_ASSERTION_ODDITIES_INEXACT_DOUBLE
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1294
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:JAO_JUNIT_ASSERTION_ODDITIES_BOOLEAN_ASSERT
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:SMA_STUTTERED_METHOD_ARGUMENTS
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:JAO_JUNIT_ASSERTION_ODDITIES_IMPOSSIBLE_NULL
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:SKIPPED_CLASS_TOO_BIG
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findsecbugs:XSS_JSP_PRINT
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:LG_LOST_LOGGER_DUE_TO_WEAK_REFERENCE
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:StringEqualityComparisonCheck
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:JAO_JUNIT_ASSERTION_ODDITIES_USE_ASSERT_EQUALS
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:JAO_JUNIT_ASSERTION_ODDITIES_ASSERT_USED
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:OBL_UNSATISFIED_OBLIGATION_EXCEPTION_EDGE
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:LowerCaseLongSuffixCheck
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:RV_RETURN_VALUE_IGNORED2
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule fb-contrib:JAO_JUNIT_ASSERTION_ODDITIES_ACTUAL_CONSTANT
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1873
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:UnusedProtectedMethod
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule squid:S1848
2016.09.25 12:46:40 INFO  web[o.s.s.r.RegisterRules] Disable rule findbugs:XSS_REQUEST_PARAMETER_TO_JSP_WRITER
2016.09.25 12:46:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register quality profiles
2016.09.25 12:46:50 INFO  ce[o.s.c.a.WebServerWatcherImpl] Still waiting for WebServer...
2016.09.25 12:46:51 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=cs, name=Sonar way}
2016.09.25 12:46:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Set default cs profile: Sonar way
2016.09.25 12:46:53 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=java, name=FindBugs + FB-Contrib}
2016.09.25 12:47:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register profile {lang=jsp, name=FindBugs Security JSP}
2016.09.25 12:47:03 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles] Set default jsp profile: FindBugs Security JSP
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters] Register measure filters
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards] Register dashboards
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates] Register permission templates
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys] Rename deprecated property keys
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.InitFilter@97f102c [pattern=/sessions/init/*]
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.MasterServletFilter] Initializing servlet filter org.sonar.server.authentication.OAuth2CallbackFilter@7ba0646e [pattern=/oauth2/callback/*]
2016.09.25 12:47:04 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index activities
2016.09.25 12:47:05 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index issues
2016.09.25 12:47:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.e.IndexerStartupTask] Index tests
2016.09.25 12:47:07 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=45804ms
2016.09.25 12:47:07 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to decompress and deserialize source data
    at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:82) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:88) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.IndexerStartupTask.execute(IndexerStartupTask.java:71) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup$1.doPrivileged(PlatformLevelStartup.java:81) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.user.DoPrivileged.execute(DoPrivileged.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevelStartup.start(PlatformLevelStartup.java:77) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.executeStartupTasks(Platform.java:201) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:114) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:99) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doRestartContainer(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:138) [sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.doDatabaseMigration(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:114) [sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration.access$000(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:37) [sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.PlatformDatabaseMigration$1.run(PlatformDatabaseMigration.java:101) [sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_92]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to decompress and deserialize source data
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Uninterruptibles.getUninterruptibly(Uninterruptibles.java:135) ~[guava-17.0.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer.index(BaseIndexer.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to decompress and deserialize source data
    at org.sonar.db.source.FileSourceDto.decodeTestData(FileSourceDto.java:167) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestResultSetIterator.read(TestResultSetIterator.java:79) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestResultSetIterator.read(TestResultSetIterator.java:60) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.ResultSetIterator.next(ResultSetIterator.java:82) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.doIndex(TestIndexer.java:93) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.doIndex(TestIndexer.java:80) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.test.index.TestIndexer.doIndex(TestIndexer.java:70) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$2.index(BaseIndexer.java:91) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.BaseIndexer$1.run(BaseIndexer.java:73) ~[sonar-server-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_92]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Stream is corrupted
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:230) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:246) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:251) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseDelimitedFrom(AbstractParser.java:49) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbFileSources$Test.parseDelimitedFrom(DbFileSources.java:4267) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.source.FileSourceDto.decodeTestData(FileSourceDto.java:160) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any hints right now. Meanwhile the ticket https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8178 has been created for version 5.6.3.

Comment: Thanks, Simon! After reading your ticket I was able to build my own SNAPSHOT version of the server jar which swallows that exception. That got me through the upgrade for the one team that really needed it. I'll wait to see how 5.6.3 shapes up before moving the other teams. I didn't trace through the code to try to output meaningful information as to what, in the data, was actually causing the problem. Thanks again :-)