# After upgrading from SonarQube 5.3 to 5.6.2, Backround Task is throwing IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops, sonarqube5.6

After upgrading from SonarQube 5.3 to Sonaeqube 5.6.2, I am unable to successfully run a scan.

Note that I am using a very slightly modified version of 5.6.2 to workaround an issue described here: [IllegalStateException when migrating databases from SonarQube 5.3 to 5.6.2 (and 5.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39691455/illegalstateexception-when-migrating-databases-from-sonarqube-5-3-to-5-6-2-and), but I'm fairly confident that has nothing to do with this issue. Completely different part of the code.

I am using version 2.1 of the gradle plugin. I have the following sonar plugins installed:

```
sonar-android-plugin-1.1.jar
sonar-build-breaker-plugin-2.1.jar
sonar-cobertura-plugin-1.7.jar
sonar-findbugs-plugin-3.4.4.jar
sonar-generic-coverage-plugin-1.2.jar
sonar-groovy-plugin-1.4.jar
sonar-java-plugin-4.2.jar
sonar-javascript-plugin-2.16.0.2922.jar
sonar-pitest-plugin-0.6.jar
sonar-piwik-plugin-1.0.jar
sonar-python-plugin-1.6.jar
sonar-timeline-plugin-1.5.jar
sonar-xml-plugin-1.4.1.jar
```

Gradle is throwing "IllegalStateException: Report processing did not complete successfully: FAILED". and the background task on the server is throwing "IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AVYt-LEmlODHqmsVS6V8]". The full stack trace can be found below.

I have examined the data in MySQL and can confirm that the row does, in fact, exist:

```
# id, kee, rule_id, severity, manual_severity, message, line, gap, status, resolution, checksum, reporter, assignee, author_login, action_plan_key, issue_attributes, effort, created_at, updated_at, issue_creation_date, issue_update_date, issue_close_date, tags, component_uuid, project_uuid, locations, issue_type
'1357', 'AVYt-LEmlODHqmsVS6V8', '1223', 'MINOR', '0', 'Define a constant instead of duplicating this literal \"Item \" 4 times.', '258', '4.00000000000000000000', 'OPEN', NULL, '1296deed4ac6511ff2f9516a1f25f984', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '', '10', '1469650091279', '1474887211270', '1469650055000', '1469650055000', NULL, 'design', 'AVYt-KA3lODHqmsVS6VG', 'AVYt-GJ8lODHqmsVS6U5', ?, '1'
```

and the locations column contains a BLOB with the following (as text):

```
ÂÂ$ +
ÂÂ$ +Duplication
ÂÂ$ +Duplication
Â½Â½& -Duplication
ÃÃ* 1Duplication
```

If anyone could shed some light on the situation, I would be very appreciative.

Cheers!

Robert

```
2016.09.26 22:41:32 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute test measures | time=6ms
2016.09.26 22:41:32 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Compute complexity measures | time=52ms
2016.09.26 22:41:32 INFO  [o.s.s.c.s.ComputationStepExecutor] Load measure computers | time=2ms
2016.09.26 22:41:32 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Failed to execute task AVdoqQI3n6cQT_03NFYE
org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException: Visit of Component {key=:md049gateway:src/main/java/com/nike/caps/md049gateway/application/impl/JobServiceImpl.java,type=FILE} failed
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitException.rethrowOrWrap(VisitException.java:44) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:100) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitChildren(VisitorsCrawler.java:100) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:87) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ExecuteVisitorsStep.execute(ExecuteVisitorsStep.java:50) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.executeSteps(ComputationStepExecutor.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.step.ComputationStepExecutor.execute(ComputationStepExecutor.java:52) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.report.ReportTaskProcessor.process(ReportTaskProcessor.java:75) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.executeTask(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:81) [sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:56) [sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.taskprocessor.CeWorkerCallableImpl.call(CeWorkerCallableImpl.java:35) [sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to process issues of component ':md049gateway:src/main/java/com/nike/caps/md049gateway/application/impl/JobServiceImpl.java'
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.IntegrateIssuesVisitor.processIssues(IntegrateIssuesVisitor.java:74) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.IntegrateIssuesVisitor.visitAny(IntegrateIssuesVisitor.java:59) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.visitAny(TypeAwareVisitorWrapper.java:82) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitNode(VisitorsCrawler.java:107) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visitImpl(VisitorsCrawler.java:90) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.component.VisitorsCrawler.visit(VisitorsCrawler.java:62) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AVYt-LEmlODHqmsVS6V8]
### The error may exist in org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper
### The error may involve org.sonar.db.issue.IssueMapper.selectNonClosedByComponentUuid-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: select           i.id,     i.kee as kee,     i.rule_id as ruleId,     i.severity as severity,     i.manual_severity as manualSeverity,     i.message as message,     i.line as line,     i.locations as locations,     i.gap as gap,     i.effort as effort,     i.status as status,     i.resolution as resolution,     i.checksum as checksum,     i.assignee as assignee,     i.author_login as authorLogin,     i.tags as tagsString,     i.issue_attributes as issueAttributes,     i.issue_creation_date as issueCreationTime,     i.issue_update_date as issueUpdateTime,     i.issue_close_date as issueCloseTime,     i.created_at as createdAt,     i.updated_at as updatedAt,     r.plugin_rule_key as ruleKey,     r.plugin_name as ruleRepo,     r.language as language,     p.kee as componentKey,     i.component_uuid as componentUuid,     p.module_uuid as moduleUuid,     p.module_uuid_path as moduleUuidPath,     p.path as filePath,     root.kee as projectKey,     i.project_uuid as projectUuid,     i.issue_type as type         from issues i     inner join rules r on r.id=i.rule_id     inner join projects p on p.uuid=i.component_uuid     inner join projects root on root.uuid=i.project_uuid     where     i.component_uuid=? and     i.status <> 'CLOSED'
### Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AVYt-LEmlODHqmsVS6V8]
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:26) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:130) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:118) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeWithResultHandler(MapperMethod.java:108) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:60) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:52) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.selectNonClosedByComponentUuid(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.BaseIssuesLoader.loadForComponentUuid(BaseIssuesLoader.java:61) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.TrackerBaseInputFactory$BaseLazyInput.loadIssues(TrackerBaseInputFactory.java:78) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.issue.tracking.LazyInput.getIssues(LazyInput.java:50) ~[sonar-core-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.issue.tracking.Tracking.<init>(Tracking.java:58) ~[sonar-core-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.core.issue.tracking.Tracker.track(Tracker.java:37) ~[sonar-core-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.TrackerExecution.track(TrackerExecution.java:41) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.IntegrateIssuesVisitor.processIssues(IntegrateIssuesVisitor.java:67) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to read ISSUES.LOCATIONS [KEE=AVYt-LEmlODHqmsVS6V8]
    at org.sonar.db.issue.IssueDto.parseLocations(IssueDto.java:655) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.issue.IssueDto.toDefaultIssue(IssueDto.java:724) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.computation.issue.BaseIssuesLoader$1.handleResult(BaseIssuesLoader.java:64) ~[sonar-server-5.6.3-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.callResultHandler(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:306) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.storeObject(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:300) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValuesForSimpleResultMap(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:292) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:266) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:239) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.DefaultResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(DefaultResultSetHandler.java:150) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:60) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:73) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.ReuseExecutor.doQuery(ReuseExecutor.java:57) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:137) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:96) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:77) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.select(DefaultSqlSession.java:128) ~[mybatis-3.2.7.jar:3.2.7]
    ... 38 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either that the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.truncatedMessage(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:70) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readRawBytesSlowPath(CodedInputStream.java:1179) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readBytes(CodedInputStream.java:517) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Location.<init>(DbIssues.java:1674) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Location.<init>(DbIssues.java:1614) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Location$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:2407) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Location$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:2401) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:495) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Flow.<init>(DbIssues.java:954) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Flow.<init>(DbIssues.java:910) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Flow$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:1527) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Flow$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:1521) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:495) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations.<init>(DbIssues.java:112) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations.<init>(DbIssues.java:55) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:852) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations$1.parsePartialFrom(DbIssues.java:846) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:137) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:169) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:49) ~[protobuf-java-3.0.0-beta-2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.protobuf.DbIssues$Locations.parseFrom(DbIssues.java:253) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.db.issue.IssueDto.parseLocations(IssueDto.java:653) ~[sonar-db-5.6.2.jar:na]
    ... 54 common frames omitted
2016.09.26 22:41:32 ERROR [o.s.s.c.t.CeWorkerCallableImpl] Executed task | project=:md049gateway | type=REPORT | id=AVdoqQI3n6cQT_03NFYE | time=1642ms
```

Comment: As you faced a similar issue yesterday, I have the feeling that there's an issue with LOBs in your database. Do you have specific configurations ?

Comment: The only customization I can see for this project is that they defined their own Quality Profile. Tried switching it to a standard one, but made no difference. I then deleted the row mentioned in the exception from the database. Now I'm getting "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded" when analyzing the project - and I've given it 4GB of heap space. It's not a very large project. Something is clearly wrong, but I don't know what it could be. I will try deleting the project completely and see what happens.

Comment: Deleting the project through the UI made no difference. However, this is clearly a different issue as the exception is thrown by gradle - it's not even getting as far as the server. I'm going to close this question, as it seems likely that there is some corruption in our databases. Hopefully the linked fix in 5.6.3 will help us track it down. Thanks for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be due to some sort of corruption in our databases. Hopefully, the changes being made in 5.6.3 (see linked question) will allow us to track down the issue.

Comment: I don't see the link with https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-8178. It won't resolve this problem.